# Make a layout in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm beginner in game development (I'm doing one with JS)  and I have one question about how to generate a layout in canvas similar like balls of billar (the image)

[image]

Thanks!

**I'm sorry, explain my question incorrectly**

The real question is: how to generate this kind of grid or pattern in the shape of a triangle or pyramid, no matter the figure is inside of the triangle or pyramid.

My game is a beer pong, so the figure inside the triangle or pyramid are 
plastic cups and for each level there will be more:

level 1: 2 plastic cups

level 2: 3 plastic cups

level x: x plastic cups

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you if you run into some issues while you are making that, but we are not gonna do your work.

Comment: Your question is a legitimate question. The problem is clear and the answer straight forward and of genuine use to many who may need to solve this very problem.To others a quick look at the related question along the right of this page will show many top answers without a line of code, Please take the time read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It is not a reason to close questions, rather a guide on how to get the best answers,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each circle is at the vertices of an equilateral triangle. The length of each side is 2 times the radius and the inside angles are 60deg

To find the position at a bearing (angle) and distance

```
var x = Math.cos(angle) * distance;
var y = Math.sin(angle) * distance;
```

The angle is in radians I will assume you know how to use radians.

Thus starting at one circle at x,y

```js
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
var x = 100
var y = 60
var radius = 50;
var r = radius; // to save typing

ctx.beginPath();

// draw first 3 circles
ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2);
ctx.moveTo(x + r * 3,y);       // Move the path to the start of the next 
                               // circle to the right of the first.
                               // Circles start their path at the 3oclock mark
                               // The second last argument 0 (Radians) and goes around
                               // clock wise to Math.PI * 2 (360Deg)
                               // 0 is the start bearing for the canvas
                               // going right along the x axis
ctx.arc(x + r * 2,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2);  // Draw the next circle 2*radius right of the first
ctx.moveTo(x + r * 5,y);       // move to start of 3rd circle
ctx.arc(x + r * 4 ,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2);  // draw the circle on the far right 
                                        // of the first row

// now find the next row which is on the line at 60 deg from the first and 2 * the radius
x += Math.cos(Math.PI / 3) * r * 2; // Math.PI / 3 is 60 deg (1 third of 180)
y += Math.sin(Math.PI / 3) * r * 2;

// draw the next two
ctx.moveTo(x + r,y);
ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2);
ctx.moveTo(x + r * 3,y);
ctx.arc(x + r * 2,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2);

// and find the location of the last circle
x += Math.cos(Math.PI / 3) * r * 2;
y += Math.sin(Math.PI / 3) * r * 2;
ctx.moveTo(x + r,y);
ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2);
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.stroke()
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px black solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width = 400 height = 300></canvas>
```

Or to put it all in a function that can do any size

```js
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");

function strokeCircle(x,y,r){  // position x,y and radius
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.moveTo(x + r,y); 
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2); 
    ctx.stroke(); 
}

// baseCount is number of circles across the top
// x,y is position of top left most circle
// r is radius
function drawCirclePyramid(baseCount,x,y,r){
    for(var i = 0; i < baseCount; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < baseCount - i; j++){
            strokeCircle(x + j * r * 2, y, r);  // big circle
            strokeCircle(x + j * r * 2, y, r * 0.2); // small inner circle
        }
        x += Math.cos(Math.PI / 3) * r * 2;  // move to next row
        y += Math.sin(Math.PI / 3) * r * 2;
    }
}

ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)
drawCirclePyramid(2,30,30,30);
drawCirclePyramid(3,160,30,30);
drawCirclePyramid(4,20,140,15);
drawCirclePyramid(5,160,200,15);
```

```css
    canvas { border : 2px black solid;}
```

```html
    <canvas id="can" width = 350 height = 330></canvas>
```